# what is the equivalent to newsoft json in android

Tags: android, json

i have problems i am searching and cant understand what type of json parser i can use for example i have local json and i want to prase it is there any sdk i can use near the newsoft json or ez to learn because i am windows phone and 8.1 developer and i sucks with android and i really need it for graduation project i created almost every thing

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "time": 40,
    "srcLong": 35.909124,
    "srcLat": 31.973628,
    "destLong": 35.898258,
    "destLat": 31.985622,
    "subSites": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "location 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "location 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "location 3"
        }
    ]
}]
```

plz how to get the response for example the code in newsoft json is like this

```
var serviceUri = "http://localhost:24728/api/sites";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(serviceUri);
var datafile = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject (((string)datafile).Substring(1, ((string)datafile).Length - 2));
```

and of course you create the class to deal with object plz can some one help me with this and i need to remove the [] to be json object i just need the sdk i should use and where to start learn and if there no problem to tell me how to substring it and to put this code

```
string uri = "http://localhost:24728/api/sites/1";
HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, data);
```

plz is there any equivalent in android.

Regards,
Ayesh.

Comment: Sorry am confused a bit, so you are just attempting to remove the [] from your string json Array? And something from the sdk?

Comment: Is there any thing equivalent to get json and post jon to URL ?? i dont know how to get data and post data in android

Comment: The code above are in C# and newsoft json sdk and thats how you get the response in that library i am stuck at getting the response in android i dont know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from what you are saying it looks like you are unsure of how to get a response from the site, maybe you do not understand how to access the url initially.  Or potentially that once you get the response and it is prehaps a string you do not know how to convert it into JSON to extract the information.  [Send information from android application to a Web Service and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153255/send-information-from-android-application-to-a-web-service-and-back).  This link has a basic version of connecting to a url. And when you have a string, you can use JSONObject and JSONArrays to grab the information on that string, you can do JSONArray(string).

Comment: so this one for httppost and i can use httpget :D ty bro

Comment: There are many libraries such as:

https://github.com/google/gson
https://github.com/square/moshi